# MPMoviePlayer Audio Album art

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am streaming an MP3 file using MPMoviePlayer, and I would like to have an image displayed instead of the default Quicktime logo in the background.

I found out a way to have an image overlay the player, but the problem with that, is you have to tap outside the image to get the player controls to appear.  And when they do appear, they are underneath the image.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most every app on the iPhone is made of a hierarchy of views. You could go up to the top root node of the movie player and walk down the child views recursively and set the `hidden` value to YES until you find the right item, then insert your `UIImageView` below that item. That way, the controls stay on top and still respond to user inputs.

The risk you run is if Apple changes the `MPMoviePlayer` UI and shuffles the view hierarchy, but you'll probably have lots of advance notice and can patch your app to allow for the new layout.

There is a question as to whether this is kosher for appstore apps, but many current apps (especially camera/picture-taking ones) are doing it to get rid of standard window elements.

Comment: I found if you do a depth first search, the one you want to add the UIImageView to as a subview is the first one you visit.

Answer (score 2):

backgroundColor is deprecated, and diving into private View structures is dangerous.  This worked fine for me:

```
        UIImageView *coverImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:coverImage];
        coverImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        coverImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        coverImageView.frame = moviePlayerController.view.bounds;
        [moviePlayerController.view addSubview:coverImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AVAudioPlayer and implement your own player UI.

Answer (score 0):

it will work check this

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
moviePlayerController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
```